# Asp.Net bind string from resources to ListItem

Tags: asp.net

I have following code.

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="CurrencyList" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CurrencyList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResourceBms", "RentPage2FilterByLabel")%>" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

This code throws

> Parser Error Message: Literal expressions like '<%$ GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResourceBms", "RentPage2FilterByLabel")%>' are not allowed. Use " /> instead.

How to this thing in Asp.NET , I need to get string from resources and put it as Item of dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
<%# GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResourceBms","RentPage2FilterByLabel" ) %>
```

**EDIT**

You will need to add the items in a different way.

Populate your ddl, using the rowdatabound method. Look:

```
public void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("CurrencyList");
        //items.

    }
}
```

Comment: Literal content ('<asp:ListItem Text="') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection'.

Comment: Thanks man , but I am kind in shock that ASP.NET doesn't have support for this to do in markup.

Answer (score 4):

Am I "a bit" late? It may help someone else nonetheless.
The <%$ %> syntax does not allow coding expressions. Use:

```
<asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources:GlobalResourceBms, RentPage2FilterByLabel %>" Value="-1" />
```